# Qgis or Python: converting a CSV file of simple locations to raster?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, raster, qgis

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
Diversity,Longitude,Latitude
7,114.99638889,-33.85333333
6,114.99790583,-33.85214594
10,115,-33.85416667
2,115.0252075,-33.84447519
```

I would like to convert it to a raster file with a set 'no data' value over most of the area and the values in cells at the long/lat locations.

Is there an easy way to do that in Qgis or python?
Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for, but here is how you can approach it in R

get the data:

```
d <- read.csv('file.csv')
d <- cbind(d[,2:3], d[,1])
```

load the raster package:

```
library(raster)
```

If your data are regularly spaced:

```
r <- rasterFromXYZ(d)
writeRaster(r, 'file.tif')
```

else create an empty raster and rasterize:

```
r <- raster(extent(d[,1:2]))
res(r) <- 1  # adjust this and other parameters as you see fit
r <- rasterize(d[,1:2], d[,3], fun=mean)
```